# Почему я не вижу примонтированной директории с volume'ом?

Tags: docker

Я запускаю докер-контейнек с volume'ом:

```
docker run --cidfile ./metadataCid.txt -e CONTAINER_USER=$CONTAINER_USER -v /home/project_manager/projects/prcamm/manager/shared/dataframe:/var/dataframes
```

Но когда я захожу внутрь файловой системы контейнера через:

```
docker run -it image_name sh
```

Этого volume'а просто нет. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: То есть нет директории /var/dataframes ?

Comment: @YakovPermyakov Именно.

Comment: как именно проверяете что ее нет?

Comment: Надо второй командой использовать docker exec [Id контейнера] , иначе вы просто запускаете ещё 1 контейнер, но без вашего тома

Comment: @YakovPermyakov Второй командой, она позволяет интерактивно исследовать контейнер.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вторая команда выполняется во втором контейнере, который ничего не знает про первый.

> Run a command in a **new** container

-- из справки `docker help run`

Нужно либо подсоединиться к первому, либо запустить второй контейнер с аналогичными параметрами (но тогда у вас будет два работающих приложения, я думаю это вам не подходит).

Поэтому выясняем ID контейнера

`docker ps`

у меня:

```
CONTAINER ID  IMAGE           COMMAND                 CREATED        STATUS       PORTS
9600da0bb443  lamp_php54-fpm  "php-fpm"               4 months ago   Up 2 weeks   9000/tcp
6a0931393c05  mongo           "docker-entrypoint.s…"  4 months ago   Up 2 weeks   27017/tcp
d5c4dabced3a  lamp_sphinx     "/bin/sh -c 'crond &…"  4 months ago   Up 2 weeks
```

Выбираем из этого списка тот, что нужен, я в примере выбрал `mongo`. Теперь входим в него:

```
docker exec -it 6a0931393c05 sh
```

Так как ID контейнеров меняются, полезно при `docker run` использовать название (`--name lamp_mongo_1`), тогда будет более удобно:

```
docker exec -it lamp_mongo_1 sh
```

Comment: Вы же понимаете, что я просто привел пример сигнатуру команды, которая позволяет интерактивно исследовать контент контейнера, естественно я подставил правильный id.

Comment: @kaylil_01, вы используете `docker run`, а надо `docker exec`

Comment: -it не создает контейнер, она создает tty, чтобы можно было ходить внутри файловой системы.

Comment: @kaylil_01, причем тут `-it`? `docker run` **создает новый** контейнер на основа образа. как вы собираетесь увидеть в **новом втором** контейнере том из **первого**? Поймите, чтобы подрубиться к первому, нужно использовать `docker exec`

Comment: т.е. я правильно понимаю, что создается новый контейнер и уже в нем запускается шелл? Проблема в том, что мой контейнер он отрабатывает и ложиться, я думал, что таким образом можно посмотреть внутреннее устройство уже пробежавшего контейнера.

Comment: @kaylil_01, да вы правильно понимаете. делайте `docker run --rm -it ваш-образ sh`, и уже в баше запускаете свою программу и отлаживаете ее. контейнер останавливается, когда отрабатывает `CMD`. Если не знаете что там, то `docker inspect контейнер | grep Cmd -A10`. Если команда - не демон, то контейнер завершается после ее выполнения, а не "висит в воздухе". Но это уже другой вопрос. Также можно исследовать файловую систему завершенного контейнера `docker export ваш-контейнер > image.tar`